# Simple method to run docker or docker-compose with the same UID/GID as parent user?

Tags: bash, docker

When I use docker or docker-compose with volumes I often have issues with permissions as the container user is not known on the host:

```
mkdir i-can-to-what-i-want
rmdir i-can-to-what-i-want
docker run -v$(pwd):/home -w/home ubuntu touch you-shall-not-delete-it
$ ls -al you-shall-not-delete-it
-rw-r--r--  2 root   root   0 2020-08-08 00:11 you-shall-not-delete-it
```

One solution is to always do this:

```
UID=$(id -u) GID=$(id -g) docker-compose up
```

Or

```
UID=$(id -u) GID=$(id -g) docker run ...
```

But... it is cumbersome...

Any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--user` will do the job, unless this is the exact cumbersome solution that you are trying to avoid:

```
who
neo      tty7         2020-08-08 04:46 (:0)

docker run --user $UID:$GID -v$(pwd):/home -w/home ubuntu touch you-shall-delete-it

ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 neo neo 4096 Aug  8 02:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 34 neo neo 4096 Aug  8 02:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 neo neo 4096 Aug  8 02:03 i-can-to-what-i-want
-rw-r--r--  1 neo neo    0 Aug  8 02:12 you-shall-delete-it
```

Comment: Well, in a sense yes, but you need to define UID and GID first, and it cannot be part of the docker-compose

Comment: UID should be there, according to the POSIX sh standard. You could export the GID in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`: `cat ~/.bashrc | grep GID ==>>
export GID=$(id -g)`

Answer (score 1):

In fact you don't use [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) here :

```
docker run -v$(pwd):/home
```

you use [bind mound.](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)
When you use a bind mount, the resource on the host machine is mounted into a container.
Relying on the host machine’s filesystem has advantages (speed and a dynamic data source) but has also its limitations (file ownership and portability).

How I see things :

1)When you use docker-compose in dev and that you need to bind your source code that constantly changes, bind mount is unavoidable but you can simplify things by setting the user/group of the container directly in the compose.

```
version: '3.5'
services:
   app:
     user: "${UID}:${GID}"
     ...
```

Note that `${UID}` and `${GID}` are here shell variables.
`${UID}` is defined in `bash`, but `${GID}` is not. You could export it if required or so use the user id for both :          `user: "${UID}:${UID}"`.

2)When you use docker or docker-compose in a frame where you don't need to provide the files/folders from that host at container creation time but that you can do it in the image creation, favor volume (name volume) over bind mount.